# Is the "Oh oh oh ah oh" chanting before a Lost episode the Lost theme song, or an ABC song?

Tags: soundtrack, lost

I am watching the 2004-2010 ABC TV series *Lost* on Netflix. I didn't watch it or anything on ABC network TV in 2004-2010, so I don't know the answer to this question.

What I'm talking about:
At the start of (or before?) each episode of Lost as shown on Netflix, there is a still image of the *Lost* logo and cast, and the ABC logo, and the sound of some people chanting a wordless song like "Oh oh oh ah oh".

Is that "song" specifically for *Lost*, or is it just an ABC theme song (or imaginary spontaneous excitement of the ABC audience?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It's an ABC song.

The same chant and logo format is used for fellow ABC program *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D*. You can see for yourself [here](https://www.netflix.com/watch/70297315?trackId=13752289&tctx=0%2C0%2C2ac55514-2f33-4bd8-b0f3-6f12d6e413c3-33847559), if you have a Netflix account.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome! One of my last remaining mysteries about Lost is now solved!